# Heroku app successfully pushed but will not open

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

Below is the log when I deploy/push to Heroku. I'm very new to this and have tried extensive research on what could be the root error but alas, I must ask. I've had a running app on Heroku before, but I've made some changes locally and then deleted the Heroku app and decided to change the remote. Here is a link to my Github: https://github.com/tomtam6/tom-tam.git

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  6.11.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   3.10.10

       Resolving node version 6.11.0...
       Downloading and installing node 6.11.0...
       npm 3.10.10 already installed with node
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules (exists - skipping)
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       body-parser@1.17.2 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/body-parser
       bytes@2.4.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/bytes
       content-type@1.0.2 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/content-type
       debug@2.6.7 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/debug
       ms@2.0.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/ms
       depd@1.1.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/depd
       http-errors@1.6.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/http-errors
       inherits@2.0.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/inherits
       setprototypeof@1.0.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/setprototypeof
       statuses@1.3.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/statuses
       iconv-lite@0.4.15 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/iconv-lite
       on-finished@2.3.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/on-finished
       ee-first@1.1.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/ee-first
       qs@6.4.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/qs
       raw-body@2.2.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/raw-body
       unpipe@1.0.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/unpipe
       type-is@1.6.15 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/type-is
       media-typer@0.3.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/media-typer
       mime-types@2.1.16 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/mime-types
       mime-db@1.29.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/mime-db
       cookie-parser@1.4.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/cookie-parser
       cookie@0.3.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/cookie
       cookie-signature@1.0.6 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/cookie-signature
       debug@2.6.8 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/debug
       ejs@2.5.6 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/ejs
       express@4.15.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/express
       accepts@1.3.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/accepts
       negotiator@0.6.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/negotiator
       array-flatten@1.1.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/array-flatten
       content-disposition@0.5.2 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/content-disposition
       debug@2.6.7 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/express/node_modules/debug
       encodeurl@1.0.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/encodeurl
       escape-html@1.0.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/escape-html
       etag@1.8.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/etag
       finalhandler@1.0.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/finalhandler
       debug@2.6.7 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/debug
       parseurl@1.3.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/parseurl
       fresh@0.5.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/fresh
       merge-descriptors@1.0.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/merge-descriptors
       methods@1.1.2 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/methods
       path-to-regexp@0.1.7 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/path-to-regexp
       proxy-addr@1.1.4 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/proxy-addr
       forwarded@0.1.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/forwarded
       ipaddr.js@1.3.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/ipaddr.js
       range-parser@1.2.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/range-parser
       send@0.15.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/send
       debug@2.6.7 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/send/node_modules/debug
       destroy@1.0.4 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/destroy
       mime@1.3.4 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/mime
       serve-static@1.12.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/serve-static
       utils-merge@1.0.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/utils-merge
       vary@1.1.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/vary
       morgan@1.8.2 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/morgan
       basic-auth@1.1.0 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/basic-auth
       on-headers@1.0.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/on-headers
       serve-favicon@2.4.3 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/serve-favicon
       safe-buffer@5.0.1 /tmp/build_af04dccbe55a579f742b63b9b9775aa9/node_modules/safe-buffer
       Installing any new modules (package.json)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 14.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v4
       https://tom-tam.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check out your heroku desktop, in the "overview" tab for your app, does it show that your last build succeeded or failed?

[image]

And when you check out the logs, does it show the app is up and running?

[image]

--edit based on comment discussion--

Add this to app.js, before `module.exports = app;`

`` const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000; app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`); }); ``

Comment: I've had a build seem to succeed, but then halt due to errors encountered after the build.

Comment: I also don't see where you start your app in app.js. Something like ```const app = require('./app');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: Build succeeded, no activity on the log. Blank & grey.

Comment: Add this before your `module.exports` line in app.js ```const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000; app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`); });```

Comment: Also, I recommend you `.gitignore` your node_modules folder. The downloading of your modules is part of the build on heroku.

Comment: Success! LexJacobs, I really appreciate you taking the time to go through my issue.

Comment: Can you expand on the .gitignore or should I just Google it?

Comment: No problem! I edited my answer to include the solution. If you could select my answer, that would be much appreciated. Here's a good overview: https://chaseadams.io/2015/07/my-gitignore-conventions/ . You just include the file at the root level of your project directory,  as `/.gitignore`